# Debezium Kafka Connect Error - TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium, confluent-platform

I'm getting an error on Debezium connect producer, and not sure where I'm making mistake or missing out something.Below are the properties for my connector and docker file. Is it possible that docker deployed on VM not able to connect it the database on other VM?

```
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:00,202] ERROR [Procura_CDC|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=Procura_CDC-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
kafka-connect-10    | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:00,203] ERROR [Procura_CDC|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=Procura_CDC-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:180)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:00,205] INFO [Procura_CDC|task-0] [Producer clientId=procura-dbhistory] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1183)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:00,374] INFO [Procura_CDC|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-Procura_CDC-0] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1183)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:12,772] INFO [Procura_CDC|task-0|offsets] WorkerSourceTask{id=Procura_CDC-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:416)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:12,773] INFO [Procura_CDC|task-0|offsets] WorkerSourceTask{id=Procura_CDC-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:433)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:12,918] INFO [Procura_CDC|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=Procura_CDC-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:416)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:12,930] INFO [Procura_CDC|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=Procura_CDC-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:433)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:12,930] ERROR [Procura_CDC|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=Procura_CDC-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:179)
kafka-connect-10    | org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:12,931] ERROR [Procura_CDC|task-0] WorkerSourceTask{id=Procura_CDC-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:180)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:12,932] INFO [Procura_CDC|task-0] [Producer clientId=procura-dbhistory] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1183)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:13,038] ERROR [Procura_CDC|task-0] Unable to unregister the MBean 'debezium.sql_server:type=connector-metrics,context=schema-history,server=procura' (io.debezium.relational.history.DatabaseHistoryMetrics:65)
kafka-connect-10    | [2020-01-23 23:37:13,039] INFO [Procura_CDC|task-0] [Producer clientId=connector-producer-Procura_CDC-0] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 30000 ms. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer:1183)
```

Docker File:

```
version: '3'
services:

  kafka-connect-02:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:latest
    container_name: kafka-connect-02
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_LOG4J_APPENDER_STDOUT_LAYOUT_CONVERSIONPATTERN: "[%d] %p %X{connector.context}%m (%c:%L)%n"
      CONNECT_CUB_KAFKA_TIMEOUT: 300
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "https://***9092"
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 'kafka-connect-02'
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: _kafka-connect-group-01-v04
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-group-01-v04-configs
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-group-01-v04-offsets
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: _kafka-connect-group-01-v04-status
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "https://***9092"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_SOURCE: "USER_INFO"
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_BASIC_AUTH_USER_INFO: "***:***"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "https://***9092"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_BASIC_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_SOURCE: "USER_INFO"
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_BASIC_AUTH_USER_INFO: "***:***"
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter'
      CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_ROOT_LOGLEVEL: 'INFO'
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: 'org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest=WARN,org.reflections=ERROR'
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '3'
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '3'
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: '3'
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: '/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/'
      # Confluent Cloud config
      CONNECT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS: "20000"
      CONNECT_RETRY_BACKOFF_MS: "500"
      CONNECT_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: "https"
      CONNECT_SASL_MECHANISM: "PLAIN"
      CONNECT_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SASL_SSL"
      CONNECT_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"***\" password=\"**";"
      #
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SASL_SSL"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: "https"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_MECHANISM: "PLAIN"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"***\" password=\"**";"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS: "20000"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_RETRY_BACKOFF_MS: "500"
      #
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL: "SASL_SSL"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM: "https"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_MECHANISM: "PLAIN"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG: "org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username=\"***\" password=\"**";"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS: "20000"
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_RETRY_BACKOFF_MS: "500"
      # External secrets config
      # See https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/security.html#externalizing-secrets
      CONNECT_CONFIG_PROVIDERS: 'file'
      CONNECT_CONFIG_PROVIDERS_FILE_CLASS: 'org.apache.kafka.common.config.provider.FileConfigProvider'
    command: 
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
        echo "Installing connector plugins"
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt debezium/debezium-connector-sqlserver:0.10.0
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt snowflakeinc/snowflake-kafka-connector:0.5.5
        #
        echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run &  

        #
        sleep infinity
```

Debezium Connector:

```
 curl -i -X PUT -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8083/connectors/Procura_CDC/config  -d '{  "connector.class":"io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector",
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "database.server.name":"***",
    "database.hostname":"***",
    "database.port":"***",
    "database.user":"Kafka",
    "database.password":"***",
    "database.dbname":"Procura_Prod",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers":"*****",
    "database.history.kafka.topic":"dbhistory.procura",
    "table.whitelist":"dbo.CLIENTS,dbo.VISITS",
    "poll.interval.ms":"2000",
    "snapshot.fetch.size":"2000",
    "snapshot.mode":"initial",
    "snapshot.isolation.mode":"snapshot",
    "transforms":"unwrap,dropPrefix",
    "transforms.unwrap.type":"io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones":"false",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"rewrite",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"procura.dbo.(.*)",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"$1" }'
```

Thanks

Comment: Please edit question with `http://localhost:8083/connectors/Procura_CDC/status` output

Comment: `CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` should not have `https:` on it

Comment: `Timeout expired while fetching topic metadata` typically means the connection to the bootstrap is failing

Comment: Where are your Kafka brokers? Are they in the same Docker Compose (if so please update your question with the full Docker Compose) or are they elsewhere? This error usually means that you've misconfigured the connection to them.

Comment: I'm running kafka brokers on confluent cloud and connectors on Docker Compose. @RobinMoffatt

Comment: Again, please show status endpoint output and remove `https` from configs

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying it's failing to connect to Kafka.

The following should not have `https://` applied to them

- `CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS`
- `CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM`
- `CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM`

In fact, not even sure the last two are valid configs.

---

You also might want to remove `REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS` and `RETRY_BACKOFF_MS` configs unless you have a specific use-case for setting those

---

And AFAIK, `CONFIG_PROVIDERS_FILE_CLASS` isn't needed because file is the default implementation.

Tip: use an `.env` file to reduce the amount of variables needed in the YAML

Comment: May I know how to configure CONNECT_CONSUMER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM and CONNECT_PRODUCER_SSL_ENDPOINT_IDENTIFICATION_ALGORITHM as I'm running the brokers on CC and debezium connector on on-premise? Any useful might be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Ssl is not mandatory, no. But using Confluent Cloud, then it is enforced. Consumers and producers do not have "endpoints"... Please show me where you've found that setting.

Comment: @Raj Did you solve this? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Simon Make sure you have mentioned essential connector values in both the docker image and kafka connect. In my case, I didn't mention key and converter value converters in my connector.

Comment: @Raj The connector doesn't need to. They would also be defined at the worker level. If this answered your question, please accept the solution

Comment: @Simon - This answer is for the listed question. As pointed out, HTTP doesn't apply to Kafka . Try posting a new question with your own config and error

Answer (score 0):

We had to increase the timeout for consumer and that helped in navigating this issue.
`ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG` increased this to `60000`.

This variable is a property of `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig`